# Python pop() method is not removing an element of a list when adding that element to another list

Tags: python, list

I have a list that contains integer elements. I wanted to split the elements into 2 lists. One should contain single digits, another one should contain multi-digit elements. After adding the elements to another list I wanted to remove that element from my main list. I use the pop() method to remove an element when putting it to another list but pop() is not popping.

You can find my code below.

```
K = [15, -10, 9, 16, 7, -99, 27, 4001, 305]
single =[]
multi=[]
i = -1
for num in K:
    i += 1
    if num > 9 or num < -9:
        multi.append(num)  # o sayiyi multi listesine ekle
    else:
        single.append(num)
    K.pop(i)
    
print(single)
print(multi)
print(K)
```

Output:

```
[9,7]
[15, 27, 305]
[-10, 16, -99, 4001]
```

As you see at the end of the algorithm K should be empty. I don't want to use clear method. I want to remove the element while putting the element to another list.

Answer (score 0):

That is because both the list decrease and the index increase, so that skips on value on each iteration

```
i  num  K
0   15  [15, -10, 9, 16, 7, -99, 27, 4001, 305]
1    9  [-10, 9, 16, 7, -99, 27, 4001, 305]
2    7  [-10, 16, 7, -99, 27, 4001, 305]
3   27  [-10, 16, -99, 27, 4001, 305]
4  305  [-10, 16, -99, 4001, 305]
```

You may use a a `while` loop

```
while K:
    num = K.pop(0)
    if num > 9 or num < -9:
        multi.append(num)
    else:
        single.append(num)
```

Comment: Thanks for your helping. The problem has been solved.

Comment: @efran You may think about [accepting an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to reward those how helped you, or at least comment to explain what's missing ;)